# google map v2 is not working after updating google play

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play

some time ago my hdd died, and i got a new one. So i reinstalled android sdk,  my app worked, but now the map is blank. I even created new android key for my new sha1, but still the map is blank, maybe something wrong with my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.poputkaonline"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.poputkaonline.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationroutedirectionmapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service android:name="com.library.GPSService" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.poputkaonline.DashboardActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.poputkaonline.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.poputkaonline.ChoiceActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_choice"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.poputkaonline.RegWithoutRegionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_reg_without_region"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.poputkaonline.RegwithoutregionStepTwoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_regwithoutregion_step_two"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.poputkaonline.RegWithoutRegionDriverActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_reg_without_region_driver"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.poputkaonline.RegwithoutRegionDriverStepTwoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_regwithout_region_driver_step_two"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.poputkaonline.RegWithoutRegionStepThreeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_reg_without_region_step_three"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.poputkaonline.MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
             android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />   
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBqgOoGExrrm5em04onPFTVktlLH5k04Mw" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.poputkaonline.ForgetPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_forget_password" >
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="com.loaders.LoaderInbox$SimpleProvider"
            android:authorities="com.loaders.loaderinbox" />
        <provider
            android:name="com.loaders.LoaderSent$SimpleProvider"
            android:authorities="com.loaders.loadersent" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

after reinstallation in manifest i added only

```
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and changed the api_key.

what should i do to get my map work again? thanks

```
11-21 15:54:19.759: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(3185): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
11-21 15:54:19.819: D/libc(3185): [NET] getaddrinfo  hn 19, servname NULL, ai_family 0+
```

Comment: What exactly is the error, check that from the Phone Log. Only then we can help

Comment: error contacting google server. probably autentification issue

Comment: Yep. that sounds more like it. Change API Key again as answer below suggests as well

Comment: no, the map is still blank

Comment: Generate SHA1 key from the scratch and obtain API_KEY. Are you using old SHA1 key? Coz u have new HDD

Comment: no, i changed sha1 that i got from debug.keystore and generated new api_key, but didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to obtain another api key. The api key needs to be changed as we change the development environment due to change in the sha1 hash. Replace the old key with new one and you are set to go.

Comment: it didn't work. i know that i should change the key with new sha1, but still it didn't help. I'm getting sha1 key like this keytool -v -list -keystore "debug.keystore", and after password request pressed <enter> and it gave me sha1,md5, etc. is it right?

Comment: are you sure your wifi was turned on in your phone?? Without logcat thats my best guess

Comment: Finally it worked) the solution is strange, i just needed to uninstall app from te device, and install it again

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your

android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyBqgOoGExrrm5em04onPFTVktlLH5k04Mw" <------

android:value is the release key